# SSIS excel source now showing # instead of . in tab name

Tags: excel, ssis, tabs

I have an SSIS job that has been working for months and i have noticed it has error as cannot read the Spreadsheet.

The spread sheet has 10 tabs on it and is in the same format as normal. tabs are named like so 0.1 , 0.2 , 0.3 , 04 ....

However i have now noticed that the excel source recognises them now as 0#1 , 0#2 , 0#3 , 0#4 ....

Has something recently changed?

Comment: Where does the spreadsheet come from? How long has the error been occurring? You probably need to ask the source of the spreadsheet if anything has changed recently, not SO.

Comment: i have eliminated the source as i create a test spreadsheet and it happens every time. i know this has changed in the last 3-4 weeks as this is a monthly job that has now error ed. I'm now wondering if it is any kind of update on VS or Excel.

Comment: Did SQL Server get updated recently?